# Place pdf in newly created folder with same name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to generate a new folder in `Q` for each sheet with the name of that sheet and generate a PDF of that same sheet with again the name of the sheet. So for example, for sheet ‘`Sheet42`’, I want to create a PDF with the name ‘’`Sheet42`’’ in the folder `Q:\ Sheet42`.

I can generate a PDF for each sheet in an Excel file to use the name of the sheet as the name of the PDF and place it in the `Q` folder.

How do I create the new folder?

```
Sub createPDFfiles()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Fname As String
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Fname = "Q:" & ws.Name  
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Fname, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was verry close by using mkdir, you can create directory (code below). And then you just change Fname to assign file to created directory.

```
Sub createPDFfiles()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Fname As String
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
            MkDir "Q:" & ws.Name
            Fname = "Q:" & ws.Name & "\" & ws.Name
     ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        fileName:=Fname, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Next ws
End Sub
```

But you will need to check, if directory already exists, before MkDir, but it should be easy to solve for you